# How to split string in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

we have ranges like this

```
"0,5,   0,5"


"0,112, 0,118"
```

and want to split by the second comma.

Any idea?

Comment: How should the result look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the regex you split by with comma then a space after.

select regexp_split_to_array('0,112, 0,118', ', ')

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=314240fb617d18c2242bdc59510fbf21)

Supposing, there ist always at least one space after the second comma and none after the others, you could use this for the split regex:

```
SELECT
    regexp_split_to_array(ranges, ',\s+')
FROM
    t
```

This returns an array like `{"0,5","0,5"}`.

You can split both ranges into columns using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    r[1],
    r[2]
FROM (
    SELECT
        regexp_split_to_array(ranges, ',\s+') as r
    FROM
        t
) s
```

---

Edit:

TO wants to get everything after the second comma. So you need a regex for splitting, which finds the nth (here n = 2) occurrence of a comma:

```
(?:(^.*?,.*)),
```

This can be used to query the required data:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=150d5ef23d9f4b09c629b273a7de8a12)

```
SELECT
    (regexp_split_to_array(ranges, '(?:(^.*?,.*)),'))[2]
FROM
    t
```

Comment: Maybe my first message was too short.  

I have a column „A“ with the following entries – two values concatenated as string like ranges:  
`"1,6,   12,1“`  
`"0,333 0,4“`  
`"0,010, 0,010"`  

I would like to get the last value (after the second comma and withouth the following spaces).  

Result would look like this:  

`" 12,1“`  
`"0,4“`  
`"0,010"`  
  
I try to do this in postgres.

Comment: Your second example has no comma between 333 and 0, is that correct?

Comment: Extended the answer.

Comment: @Bodo Please update your question. This way, the exact question will be seen easily, rather than hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

```
select regexp_replace('0,112, 0,118', '.*,\s+', '') as foo;
```

Output:

```
  foo  
-------
 0,118
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick answers. It finally worked by using this

regexp_matches(your_string_value, '\d+[,|.]\d+|\d+','g'))[1]

This helped me getting rid of all unnecessary characters within the values + delivered me back the second value in the range.